# Continue to get "Cannot resolve symbol 'equals'" error. Also need to find current activity in a non activity class

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, equals

I am following [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/shapes.html) about using OpenGL for my Android application.

I am trying to make a conditional statement that will choose what to put in the triangleCoords variable based on the activity that it is being called from.

1. Will `String gt=this.getClass().getSimpleName();` give me the current running activity when coded in a non-activity class? What format does the code display as?
2. How can I make the `gt.equals("PlayGameType1Activity")` not have a "Cannot resolve symbol 'equals'" error message.

---

```
String gt=this.getClass().getSimpleName();
// number of coordinates per vertex in this array
static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
static float triangleCoords[];

if(gt.equals("PlayGameType1Activity"))
{
    float triangleCoords[] = {   // in counterclockwise order:
        1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,       // top
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,      // bottom left
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f       // bottom right
    };
}

if(gt.equals("PlayGameType2Activity"))
{
    float triangleCoords[] = {   // in counterclockwise order:
        1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,       // top
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,      // bottom left
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f        // bottom right
    };
}
```

[This is what my code looks like with the error colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1vYF.png)

Comment: Is this code in a method? Static variables can only be declared directly in a class (not in a method), but `if` statements must be in a method.

Answer (score 0):

1. Pass a reference to the current activity into this class and use `currentActivity.getClass().getName()`
2. Put them in a method

   ```
   private void myMethod() {
       if(gt.equals("PlayGameType1Activity"))
       {
           float triangleCoords[] = {   // in counterclockwise order:
           1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, // top
           -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom left
           -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f  // bottom right
       };

       if(gt.equals("PlayGameType2Activity"))
       {
           float triangleCoords[] = {   // in counterclockwise order:
           1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, // top
           -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom left
           -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f  // bottom right
       };
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I usually pass the context of the activity to static methods in another class.

Usually in utility.

This is an example of my utility class. Hope it helps give a vivid idea

```
public class Utility {
    public static void picassoLoader(Context context, ImageView imageView, String url){
        Log.d("PICASSO", "loading image");
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(url)
                        //.resize(30,30)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.one)
                .error(R.drawable.one)
                .into(imageView);
    }
}
```

Then in any activity i call

```
Utility.picassoLoader(this, imageview, url);
```

passing "this" as the context or pass getContext() method

```
Utility.picassoLoader(getContext(), imageview, url);
```

Sorry for using the picasso example, Ive not used OpenGL before